# Google Oauth Rediect Link throwing error in Angular

Tags: angular, google-api, google-authentication, angular7

I'm using the ux-mode redirect option with Google Sign-in authentication and the querystring that gets added to the redirect URL is causing an instant error. The login works, but this script error is causing issues.

Here's the error:

```
core.js:12632 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 
'querySelector' on 'Document': '#scope=openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&
id_token=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&prompt=consent' 
is not a valid selector.
            at BrowserViewportScroller.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.BrowserViewportScroller.scrollToAnchor
```

I've tried different URLs, and it's the same error every time. I've even tried redirecting from the redirect URL to another to try and get away from the issue parsing the querystring but this error causes all sorts of issues and it seemingly breaks the ability to use router.navigate.

Here's the config:

```
const gapiClientConfig: GapiClientConfig = {
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  discoveryDocs: [ DISCOVERYDOCS ],
  scope: [ SCOPES ].join(' '),
  ux_mode: 'redirect',
  redirect_uri: environment.redirect_uri
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error with this question. Else it is very hard to help you

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question unless you provide some information what kind of OAuth (2.0 I assume) framework you are using. And I don't know what "UX mode redirect" is and I even googled for that. You mean some sort of silent redirect in an iframe?

Comment: @phil this is Google sign in. AFAIK, they only use OAuth2. The redirect option allows a user to sign in without a pop up.

Comment: @beachCode well yeah, the endpoint is Google, but on client-side you can write the authentication-check yourself or use some code-snippet from google or a plugin (we use https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc for example). So what exactly handles the login/token-refresh/logout on your client? Whatever it is, it is calling querySelector on the HTML-document (trying to locate the redirection-iframe I guess), but as it seems, with the wrong selection argument. It needs an HTML-selector but receives the whole authentication settings as string instead. Can you show some code?